# dplyr mutate replace dynamic variable name

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code replaces the values of hwy > 25 with 1 otherwise 0.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)
mpg %>% mutate(hwybin=replace(hwy>25,1,0))
```

How would I do the replace with hwy as a variable name. Something along the lines of:

```
varname <- "hwy"
mpg %>% mutate(hwybin=replace(varname>25,1,0))
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thank you.

Comment: ah yes, you are correct. The data is part of the ggplot2 package.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to create the name `hwybin` dynamically? Or substitute `varname` dynamically?

Comment: Okay, I undeleted my answer.  I think it's what you want

Comment: `mpg %>% mutate_(hwybin=interp(~replace(varname>25, 1 ,0), varname = as.name(varname)))` ought to do it

Comment: thanks. this is the answer I was looking for. could you add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well turn the comment into an answer (and make your question reproducible):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lazyeval)

data(mpg)

a <- mpg %>% mutate(hwybin=replace(hwy>25, 1 ,0))

varname <- "hwy"
b <- mpg %>% mutate_(hwybin=interp(~replace(varname>25, 1 ,0),
                                   varname=as.name(varname)))

identical(a, b)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: followup question. how would I use the same varname for the renamed column. i.e. something like. mpg %>% mutate_(varname=interp(~replace(varname>25, 1 ,0), varname=as.name(varname)))

Comment: that would be an excellent follow-up (read: additional, new) question!

Comment: posted a followup at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194070/creating-a-column-with-replaced-values-using-mutate-and-dplyr. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
library(data.table)
mybin <- function(DF,var,thresh,suffix="bin")
  DF %>% mutate(x = + ( .[[var]] > thresh )) %>% setnames("x", paste0(var,suffix)) %>% `[`

mpg %>% mybin("hwy",25)
```

I'm sure there is some `dplyr`-flavored alternative to data.table's `setnames`, but I don't know of it.