# creating a column with replaced values using mutate and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This likely a duplicate somewhere on stackoverflow and is a followup question to [dplyr mutate replace dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193413/dplyr-mutate-replace-dynamic-variable-name).

Now I am trying to use a variable name as the new column.

Something like:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 data(mpg)
 mpg %>% mutate(hwy=replace(hwy, hwy>29,10))
```

The code below creates a new column called varname but I want to replace the column with hwy.

```
varname = "hwy"
mpg %>% mutate_(varname=interp(~replace(varname, varname>29, 10), varname=as.name(varname)))
```

Something like:

```
mpg %>% mutate_(as.name(varname)=interp(~replace(varname, varname>29, 10), varname=as.name(varname)))
```

but this doesn't work. I think the dots notation is in play but not quite sure how to wrap my head around it.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32101203/2461552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than replace `mpg`'s existing `hwy` variable I did the following to illustrate the same thing and put it into [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193413/dplyr-mutate-replace-dynamic-variable-name/32193766?noredirect=1#comment52273269_32193766):

From your previous question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lazyeval)

data(mpg)

# "normal" dplyr
a <- mpg %>% mutate(hwybin=replace(hwy>25,1,0))


# varying just the RHS
varname <- "hwy"
b <- mpg %>% mutate_(hwybin=interp(~replace(varname>25, 1 ,0),
                                   varname=as.name(varname)))

identical(a, b)
```

For this particular question:

```
# varying both RHS and LHS

colname <- "hwybin"
z <- mpg %>% mutate_(.dots=setNames(list(interp(~replace(varname>25, 1 ,0),
                            varname=as.name(varname))), colname))

# tests
identical(a, z)
identical(b, z)
```

Comment: great. thank you. the notation doesn't look elegant but it certainly does the job.